# Can't show 'predictions.jpg' from YOLOv4 detections

Tags: yolov4

I re configured the darknet and successfully detected several targets which has been output from the test command, with corresponding probablities.
However, when I tried to open up the predictions.jpg image, it always show the previous detect that has been saved by the github repo (a person with a horse) and not updating it with my target image.
Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please add the code that you ran and add details about how you compiled darknet?

Comment: Hi Thanks Parico! I have already figured it out myself using the linux console.